java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:
I am getting the driver executable does not exist on Mac; even though it is already present in the directory.
Below the code snippet, I am using.
public void setUp()
        {
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            //webDriver.get(baseUrl);
        }

Please advice
The path is correct, though but dont know why it gives this error.

chromedriver.exe sounds like it's a Windows binary - are you sure you should be using that on a Mac?

Your exception is IllegalStateException. If this were a linking problem, you'd get a NoClassDefFoundError. But the exception is "IllegalState". Maybe you haven't initialized something correctly, or maybe you are trying to reuse an Object that's not made to be reused.

Make sure you are using the newest Selenium (> 4.6 at least) and it's easier with Selenium Manager. It will download and use the appropriate Chromedriver version.
public void setUp() {
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
}

